# Calling const mutable lambdas

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

To simplify the testcase, suppose that I have the following wrapper class:

```
template <typename T>
struct Wrapper {
  decltype(auto) operator()() const {
    return m_t();
  }
  decltype(auto) operator()() {
    return m_t();
  }
  T m_t;
};

template <typename T>
auto make_wrapper(T t) {
  return Wrapper<T>{t};
}
```

And let’s say I am wrapping the following trivial functor returning references:

```
struct Foo {
  int& operator()() {
    return x;
  }
  const int& operator()() const {
    return x;
  }
  int x;
};
```

In my `main` function, I am trying to wrap the `Foo` functor into a lambda closure. Since I want it to return non-const references, I am setting it `mutable` and using `decltype(auto)`:

```
int main() {
  Foo foo;
  auto fun = [foo]() mutable -> decltype(auto) { return foo(); };
  auto wfun = make_wrapper(fun);
  const auto& cwfun = wfun;

  wfun();     // <- OK
  cwfun();    // <- BAD!
}
```

For the second call, `cwfun()`, the first `const` version of `Wrapper::operator()` is called, but there `m_t` is then viewed as a `const` lambda, and thus cannot be called. I suppose this is because `m_t` was marked `mutable` in the first place. So what would be a good way of making that work? Convert `m_t` to a non-`const` before calling it in `operator() const`?

### Goals

My goal is that the call to `cwfun()` will call `Wrapper::operator() const` and `Foo::operator() const`. I could mark `Wrapper::m_t` as `mutable` to fix the compiler error, but then `Foo::operator()` would ultimately be called instead of `Foo::operator() const`.

Alternatively, I can add a `const` in `Wrapper::operator() const` since I know that `Foo::operator()` and `Foo::operator() const` only differ by their constness. Using something like:

```
return const_cast<typename std::add_lvalue_reference<typename std::add_const<typename std::remove_reference<decltype(m_t())>::type>::type>::type>(m_t());
```

But yes, that’s heavy.

### Errors and Coliru paste

The error message given by clang looks like:

```
tc-refptr.cc:8:12: error: no matching function for call to object of type 'const (lambda at
      tc-refptr.cc:40:14)'
    return m_t();
           ^~~
tc-refptr.cc:44:27: note: in instantiation of member function 'Wrapper<(lambda at
      tc-refptr.cc:40:14)>::operator()' requested here
  DebugType<decltype(cwfun())> df;
                          ^
tc-refptr.cc:40:14: note: candidate function not viable: 'this' argument has type 'const
      (lambda at tc-refptr.cc:40:14)', but method is not marked const
  auto fun = [foo]() mutable -> decltype(auto) { return foo(); };
```

[Code on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c883cfd6d9d63f04)

Comment: Lambdas have only one function call operator or operator template. So it can only have either a `const` or a non-`const` function call operator (template). I guess what you're looking for can only be achieved with a manually written function object type, such as `Wrapper`.

Comment: What do you need the lambda for, by the way? Remove it (`auto fun = foo;`) and the rest of the code works fine.

Comment: The fact that two functions would be required make sense. It would be tedious to write, but I guess this is already the case in general C++ when you need to replicate the same content for `const` and non-`const` versions of functions. As for the lambda, it mimics an existing and required aspect of the real application.

Comment: You could use a polymorphic lambda instead, and pass in the previously wrapped function object as a parameter: `[](auto&& f) -> decltype(auto) { return f(); }`, then possibly bind this lambda to `foo` with some adapter (don't know off the top of my head if `std::bind` can be used for that..)

Comment: @dyp Again, you need a different binding for const and non const in the same object, and I don't think `bind` provides that.  So a const-sensitive binder that takes a function object and bundle of arguments, stores the arguments in a tuple, then on `()(Extra&&...)` invokes the function object with the arguments then the ones passed to `()`.  It is basically partial application with const-sensitivity.

Comment: @Yakk As I said, I didn't know off the top of my head if `std::bind` supports it. After a quick, but not very thorough search of the Standard I'd say: `std::bind` does indeed forward constness, and [implementations support it](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/dd0b2a5547e4d25f).

Answer (score 1):

First we start with `partial_apply`, which in this case is written to be const-sensitive:

```
template<class F, class...Args>
struct partial_apply_t {
  std::tuple<Args...> args;
  F f;
  template<size_t...Is, class Self, class...Extra>
  static auto apply( Self&& self, std::index_sequence<Is...>, Extra&&...extra )
  -> decltype(
    (std::forward<Self>(self).f)(
      std::get<Is>(std::forward<Self>(self).args)...,
      std::declval<Extra>()...
    )
  {
    return std::forward<Self>(self).f(
      std::get<Is>(std::forward<Self>(self).args)...,
      std::forward<Extra>(extra)...
    );
  }
  partial_apply_t(partial_apply_t const&)=default;
  partial_apply_t(partial_apply_t&&)=default;
  partial_apply_t& operator=(partial_apply_t const&)=default;
  partial_apply_t& operator=(partial_apply_t&&)=default;
  ~partial_apply_t()=default;
  template<class F0, class...Us,
    class=std::enable_if_t<
      std::is_convertible<std::tuple<F0, Us...>, std::tuple<F, Args...>>{}
    >
  >
  partial_apply_t(F0&& f0, Us&&...us):
    f(std::forward<F0>(f0)),
    args(std::forward<Us>(us)...)
  {}
  // three operator() overloads.  Could do more, but lazy:
  template<class...Extra, class Indexes=std::index_sequence_for<Extra>>
  auto operator()(Extra&&...extra)const&
  -> decltype( apply( std::declval<partial_apply_t const&>(), Indexes{}, std::declval<Extra>()... ) )
  {
    return apply( *this, Indexes{}, std::forward<Extra>(extra)... );
  }
  template<class...Extra, class Indexes=std::index_sequence_for<Extra>>
  auto operator()(Extra&&...extra)&
  -> decltype( apply( std::declval<partial_apply_t&>(), Indexes{}, std::declval<Extra>()... ) )
  {
    return apply( *this, Indexes{}, std::forward<Extra>(extra)... );
  }
  template<class...Extra, class Indexes=std::index_sequence_for<Extra>>
  auto operator()(Extra&&...extra)&&
  -> decltype( apply( std::declval<partial_apply_t&&>(), Indexes{}, std::declval<Extra>()... ) )
  {
    return apply( std::move(*this), Indexes{}, std::forward<Extra>(extra)... );
  }
};
template<class F, class... Ts>
partial_apply_t<std::decay_t<F>, std::decay_t<Ts>...>
partial_apply(F&& f, Ts&&...ts) {
  return {std::forward<F>(f), std::forward<Ts>(ts)...};
}
```

then we use it:

```
auto fun = partial_apply(
  [](auto&& foo) -> decltype(auto) { return foo(); },
  foo
);
```

now a copy of `foo` is stored in the `partial_apply`, and at the point where we invoke it it is passed (in the correct const-correctness) to the lambda.  So the lambda gets a different const-ness of `foo` depending on the call context of `fun`.

Other than the fact I probably have a typo above, the other thing it should handle is `std::ref` and the like, so that when it expands `args` it converts `std::reference_wrapper` into references.

That shouldn't be hard: a `reference_unwrapper` that passes non-reference-wrapped things through, and unwraps `std::reference_wrapper`s.

Alternatively, we could unwrap in the `partial_apply` function, instead of `decay_t`ing.